# Can't find ProjectName.dll attach process for debugging of dotnet core api in VS Code?

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-code, .net-core, web-api-testing

I am trying to debug dotnet core api in VS Code. But I can't find dotnet process to start debugging. Here is sceen shots.

Here is mine which I am getting:

[image: Mine VS Code Screen shot]

And here is what I am looking for:

[image]

You can see in my case I am getting **dotnet.exe**. But in below pic .dll. How can I get this one? A breakpoint did not hit in my case.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Make sure that you are running the project (dotnet run). After I ran the project, I found `myprojectname.exe` in the list. I attached it to the debugger and it hit the break-point. I don't know why it would not show the `projectname.dll`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could as well start a watch run (dotnet watch run) first and then start debugging. In that way you'll be more able to follow what's going on and avoid running the project each time you introduce new changes.

Answer (score 0):

When are you adding .NetCore Attach for solution through the Visual studio code, before you must build and run solution by " dotnet build and dotnet run"

Then Click on Debugger tab -> Add Configuration -> .Net Core/.NetFramework  -> select .Net core Attach for Console App -> Finally select Yourproject.dll.

"Yourproject.dll" must come if your project is already build and run mode.

-> Put the breakepoint in your Method() -> Add Run through the Browser/ Postman/Fiddler ..

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to find the process that you are looking for than you can debug your app using another configuration, ".NET Core Launch(web)" that one is gonna explicitly run the application for you and start the debugging process.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the configuration, use ".NET: Launch .NET Core Console App with a debugger." Then you can configure your path to the desired DLL file.

[image: See the image]

Answer (score 0):

try `dotnet build` first and then `dotnet run`. After that you could see projectname.dll appear when you click run button

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by cleaning my build then i get the process visible to attach debugger
steps to follow:

1. `dotnet clean`
2. `dotnet run`
3. click attach debugger
4. looking for `<name of project>.exe` in the search tab

hope it solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

If you have already built and run the project, and you want to attach the process to the debugger, you should find either DatingApp.API.dll or Dating.API.exe on the list.

Here is what you can find:

[image: Attaching process to the debugger]

Hope this might help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow these steps :

1. Click on the debug tab
2. Choose .NET Core Attach
3. Click on "start debugging button"
4. Search for "you-app-name.exe/.dll"
   If you don't find both of them, you have to check your configuration (launch.json) , you must add your .NET Core attach config under configurations Array:

   ```
   {  
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",  
        "type": "coreclr",  
        "request": "attach",  
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"  
   }
   ```